# Looking for html string jquery parser ( parse <a> links and <img>images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am Looking for html string jquery parser (  parse `<a>` links and `<img>` images) or for code that will parse all links and images from html string (Html string can be  **very big).**

**Example:**

**input**:

```
sdsds<div>sdd<a href='http://google.com/image1.gif'image1</a>  sd</div>
sdsdsdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss <p> sdsdsdsds  </p>
sdsds<div>sdd<img src='http://google.com/image1.gif'image1 alt="car for family">  sd</div>
```

**output links**: value+href (if value empty not return such link)

**output images**:src + alt

Its very important for me to find the most efficient way.

---

---

**Edit:**

the function should looks like that return multi dimensial array.

like: arr[links][href][value] arr[images][src][alt]

```
function parseLinksAndImages(htmlString){
.........................
........................
return linksAndImagesArrMultiDimensial;
}
```

**(or in other better way if you have)**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your string is valid HTML, you could do something like this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/WsDTL/2/ *(updated from original to use `.each()` instead of `.map()` in order to avoid using `.split()` )*

```
var string = "sdsds<div>sdd<a href='http://google.com/image1.gif'>image1</a>  sd</div>sdsdsdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss <p> <a href='some/href'></a> sdsdsdsds  </p>sdsds<div>sdd<img src='http://google.com/image1.gif' alt='car for family' />  sd</div>";

var $container = $('<div/>').html(string);

var result = [];

$container.find('a,img').each(function() {
    if(this.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A') {
        if($.trim( this.innerHTML ) != '') {
            result.push([this.tagName,this.innerHTML,this.href]);
        }
    } else {
        result.push([this.tagName,this.src,this.alt]);
    }
});

alert(result);​
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you meant that you don't want to process the `<a>` if it doesn't have an `href` attribute, then change the code to this:

```
$container.find('a[href],img').each(function() {
    if(this.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A') {
        result.push([this.tagName,this.innerHTML,this.href]);
    } else {
        result.push([this.tagName,this.src,this.alt]);
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

For storage as in your comment, you would make `results` a javascript object, and store the arrays under the `links` and `images` keys.

```
var string = "sdsds<div>sdd<a href='http://google.com/image1.gif'>image1</a>  sd</div>sdsdsdssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss <p> <a href='some/href'></a> sdsdsdsds  </p>sdsds<div>sdd<img src='http://google.com/image1.gif' alt='car for family' />  sd</div>";

var $container = $('<div/>').html(string);

   // store results in a javascript object
var result = {
     links:[],
     images:[]
}; 

$container.find('a[href],img').each(function() {
    if(this.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A') {
        result.links.push([this.tagName,this.innerHTML,this.href]);
    } else {
        result.images.push([this.tagName,this.src,this.alt]);
    }
});

alert(result.links);
alert(result.images);
```

You can do 2 separate loops if you prefer. Not sure which will perform better.​

http://jsfiddle.net/WsDTL/3/

Comment: Thanks its looks very efficient way, does your function make 1 iteration of the string like it looks or find function make separate iteration for a tag and after for img tag?

Comment: @Yosef - What's happening is that they are being turned into DOM elements in memory (stored in $container). The `.find()` is just a typical jQuery `.find()`. Its performance will depend on the length of the string, and the browser, but overall should be very quick.

Comment: @Yosef ...also, when you said *"(if value empty not return such link)"* I assumed you meant the "content" of the `<a>` element. Or did you mean the value of the `<a>` element's `href` attribute? If so, it should change a little. See update.

Comment: <a href="link">value</a>.About find: you use 2 tags to find with find function- my question how jquery find works - option 1:: iterate  once the string and looking for 2 tags or option 2:: first find looking for <a> after she finish to look inside the string she doing it again with <img>.(Html string can be also very big.)

Comment: can be your code improved with multi array for fetch links and images separetly?
My code edit proposal:
result=[][];
.........
if....
result['links'].push([this.tagName,this.innerHTML,this.href]);
else
result['images'].push([this.tagName,this.src,this.alt]);

Comment: @Yosef - Again, the string is not being parsed by jQuery. It is being turned into actual DOM elements. The native `getElementsByTagName()` method is being called twice, but it is very fast. It is returning only the elements you want, and processing those. It may be a little quicker to do two separate loops, only because you wouldn't need to test to see which type of element you have. But I doubt it would make much difference. I'll update my answer to place the results into separate arrays, and will let you decide if you want 2 separate loops.

Comment: Thanks you very much for great answer with explanation, I don't need 2 loops - you solution very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply go thourgh them like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if ($(this).attr('href') && $(this).text()) { // get only links with href set
      // your code...
   }
});

$('img').each(function(){
   if ($(this).attr('src') && $(this).attr('alt')) { //get images with src and alt set
     // your code...
   }
});
```

Comment: +1! To add a bit of 'backstory', you could take the string in the original question, say it's in a variable like `htmlStuff`, turn it into navigatable elements and operate on the stuff you're looking for like so: `jQuery( htmlStuff ).find('a').each(linkFunc).end().find('img').each(imgFunc);`

Comment: Thanks for answer,in your solution the string should iterated 2 times - Can be done in only 1 iteration?

Comment: @Yosef: Same iteration for what/which tag?

Comment: <a> value+href + <img> src + alt - if its possible with jquery.

Comment: Also I need parse external html string and not the webpage. function parseLinksAndImages($htmlString){..code....return linksAndImages;}

Comment: does you way working more fast for very big html string than patrick way?

Comment: @Yosef: Both ways are practically the same. The key is to run the html string through jQuery to create a DOM structure that is traversable. I'd take a nice long casual walk through the jQuery docs :)